# Django, unicode object has no attribute pk

Tags: django, unicode

I have a problem with validation of form containing ModelMultipleChoiceField.
In face on submit, I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/Proapp/main_app/views.py", line 275, in felicitationInscription
if completerProfilForm.is_valid() :
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 161, in is_valid
return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 153, in errors
self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 362, in full_clean
self._clean_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 380, in _clean_fields
value = field.clean(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1254, in clean
qs = self._check_values(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1287, in _check_values
pks = set(force_text(getattr(o, key)) for o in qs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1287, in <genexpr>
pks = set(force_text(getattr(o, key)) for o in qs)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

So my form is like this :

```
class inscritForm(forms.ModelForm) :
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta : 
        model = Inscrit
        fields = ['firstname','skills']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(inscritForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        thedomains = Domain.objects.values_list('name',flat=True)
        self.fields["skills"] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=thedomains, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        for key, field in self.fields.iteritems():
            self.fields[key].required = False
```

And the models :

```
class Inscrit(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    competences = models.ManyToManyField(Speciality,related_name='specialities')

class Domain(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self) :
        return self.name


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Speciality(models.Model):
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain,null=False)
    specificity = models.TextField(max_length=100,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s'%(self.domain.name, self.specificity)
```

And finally my validation in the view :

```
...
if request.method == "POST" :
        form = inscritForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() : # Errors here
...
```

I tested if instances of Domain have attribute 'pk' in the shell and YES they have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since are using a model multiple choice field, you should use a regular queryset instead of `values()`.

```
thedomains = Domain.objects.all()
self.fields["skills"] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=thedomains, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot this specificity... Thank's !